# ROBOT Framework- API POST - Response.content appears empty even with response successful

Tags: robotframework

**Issue:-**
ROBOT Framework- API POST - Response.content appears empty even with response successful

```
Create Session    test_session    ${baseurllosexternal}    verify=true
&{headers}=    Create Dictionary    Authentication-Token=123-123-123    Content-Type=application/json
${checkpostdata}=    Parse Json    ${Ratesearchpost_v1}
    Log To Console    ${checkpostdata}    
${Response}=    Post Request    test_session    ${RateSearch}     data=${checkpostdata}    headers=${headers}
${responseString}    Set Variable    ${response.content}
```

Library used RequestsLibrary.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Im not getting any error "Success" Response ... POST with the postman works.. im not sure that if its the header used&{headers}=    Create Dictionary    Authentication-Token=123-123-123    Content-Type=application/json

Comment: What is the response content from postman?

Comment: The response has a JSON value with data from Application

Comment: Authentication-token should be set from response that you get in the `Create Session` keyword. Are you doing that properly?

Comment: In postman i have the Authentication-token as a header. the Authentication-token is same every time.

Comment: You should consider a few points before continuing: 1. Every token should have an expiry time after which it cannot be used again. 2. Where is the `Parse Json` keyword from? Is it an external library or your custom library? 3. If you do not get any data in the response you should check the response code of the request you sent. `Log to Console  ${Response.status_code}` will give you the response code. It should be 201 for a successful request(for POST request). If it other than 201 in your case, the request is failing.